# What causes Underfull and Overfull \hbox warnings in code processed in .dtx file but not in standalone .tex file?

Tags: footnotes, tcolorbox, warnings, output

I am running TeX Live 2021 with all available package and system updates applied on macOS Catalina (again with all available updates applied). I am editing package documentation that was last processed on December 5, 2021 with `LuaLaTeX` and suddenly I see numerous `Underfull \hbox` and `Overfull \hbox` warnings that did not exist on December 5. A few `tcolorbox` environments now show line breaks where there were none before, a footnote is typesetting differently, and some verbatim text is typesetting incorrectly. The documentation is split into three `.dtx` files that are processed from the first of the three and obviously providing all that code isn't feasible, so I extracted a few specific examples into a standalone `mwe.tex` file and it processed exactly as it did on December 5. I am puzzled as to why the same code in the `.dtx` file now produces warnings. **Before today, the code had not been touched since December 5, 2021.** Of course all available updates from CTAN have been applied as usual using `tlmgr`.

I have examined the `.log` files and the only differences I see are eight `Overfull \hbox` warnings and one `Underfull \hbox` warning when the code is processed from within the `.dtx` file. They are not present when `mwe.tex` is processed and were not present on December 5.

I know both `tcolorbox` and `fontspec` have both recently been updated, but if they were the source of the problem it would have shown up in the `mwe.tex` document.

What would be different in processing this code from within a `.dtx` file that has changed since December 5?

**UPDATE:** I obviously cannot post three `.dtx` files and the `.log` file here lest I be told to pare it down to a MWE, which is what I tried to do here. The entire project is available at https://github.com/heafnerj/mandi/tree/dev in case anyone wants to investigate further.

I provide a mwe and screenshots showing the typeset output from December 5, 2021 and today (January 22, 2022).

Here is the `mwe.tex` file.

```
% !TEX program = lualatexmk
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}
\PassOptionsToPackage{listings,documentation}{tcolorbox} % prevent option clash
\usepackage{mandi}                                       % load mandi.sty
\usepackage{mandistudent}                                % load mandistudent.sty
\usepackage{mandiexp}                                    % load mandiexp.sty
\usepackage[left = 1.00in,%                              %
            right = 1.00in,%                             %
            marginparwidth = 0.70in]{geometry}           % main documentation
\usepackage[listings,documentation]{tcolorbox}           % workhorse package
\tcbset{%                                                % tcolorbox options
  index german settings,%
  index colorize = false,%
  lefthand ratio = 0.50,%
  color hyperlink = blue,%
  color command = purple,%
  color environment = purple!65!black,%
  doc left = 0.5in,%
  doc marginnote = {colframe = blue!50!white,colback = blue!5!white},%
  doc head command = {interior style = {fill,left color = blue!15!white}},%
  doc head environment = {interior style = {fill,left color = blue!15!white}},%
  doc head key = {interior style = {fill,left color = blue!15!white}},%
  docexample/.style = {%
      colback = gray!10!white,sidebyside,lefthand ratio = 0.5,center},%
  listing style = vpython,%
}%
% We need a new command for in-line listings to prevent overfull boxes.
% Anything in |...| will be in small plain text.
% Previously used !...! but that conflicts with colors.
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}                      % colored links; no borders
\lstMakeShortInline[basicstyle=\normalfont\ttfamily\small]|
\listfiles
\begin{document}
 The \textsf{mandi} \footnote{The bundle name can be pronounced either with two 
 syllables, to rhyme with \emph{candy}, or with three syllables, as 
 \emph{M and I}.} bundle consists of three packages: \textsf{mandi}, 
 \textsf{mandistudent}, and \textsf{mandiexp}.

\begin{dispExample*}{lefthand ratio = 0.80}
  \( \vec{p} \) or \( \vec*{p} \)                                         \\
  \( \vec{p}_{\symup{final}} \) or \( \vec*{p}_{\symup{final}} \)         \\
  \( \magnitude{\vec{p}} \) or \( \magnitude*{\vec{p}_{\symup{final}}} \) \\
  \( \dirvec{p} \) or \( \dirvec*{p} \)                                   \\
  \( \changein \vec{p} \) or \( \changein t \)                            \\
  \( \zerovec \) or \( \zerovec* \)                                       \\
  \( 6.02\timestento{-19} \)
\end{dispExample*}

 Commands that include the name of a physical quantity typeset units, so 
 they shouldn't be used for algebraic or symbolic values of components.
 For example, one shouldn't use |\vectormomentum{mv_x,mv_y,mv_z}| but
 instead the generic |\mivector{mv_x,mv_y,mv_z}| instead.
\end{document}
```

Here is a screenshot showing a correctly typeset `dispExample*` `tcolorbox` environment as it existed on December 5 from the `.dtx` file and today from the `mwe.tex` file.

[image: correctly typeset dispExample* environment in mwe.tex]

Here is the **exact same code** typeset today from within the `.dtx` file.

[image: incorrectly typeset dispExample* environment in dtx file]

Here is a correctly typeset paragraph containing some verbatim text as it existed on December 5 from the `.dtx` file and today from the `mwe.tex` file.

[image: correctly typeset paragraph in mwe.tex]

Here is the **exact same code** typeset today from within the `.dtx` file.

[image: incorrectly typeset paragraph in dtx file]

Finally, here is a correctly typeset footnote as it existed on December 5 from the `.dtx` file and today from the `mwe.tex` file.

[image: correctly typeset footnote in mwe.tex]

And here is the **exact same code** typeset today from within the `.dtx` file.

[image: incorrectly typeset paragraph in dtx file]

Comment: It's a bit hard to follow your question, there is no reason to assume a dtx and the tex file have the same page size so can have different linebreaking, if the linebreaking of the tex changed we could look at that, I tried the tex with todays texlive and got the wider layout, I tried comparing with texlive 2020 but the mandistudent file wasn't installed then

Comment: @DavidCarlisle They always have before and I've never seen a case where the two differed in well over a decade. I just re-ran the mwe and got the narrower layout again. Now our personal installations don't give the same result for some reason. Something somewhere has changed.

Comment: I can't follow the question, if you forget the "dtx file" (as you have not posted that) and concentrate on the tex shown.  please show the output you get, and the log file

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I cannot post the entire project here of course without incurring the wrath of the MWE crowd (that's why I didn't). Everything is available at https://github.com/heafnerj/mandi/tree/dev in case anyone wants to investigate.

Comment: fine but you need to post something that people can answer. I have run the tex file posted with a current texlive and got the wider layout shown in the top image. So that's all I can possibly say but as far as I can tell that isn't the answer you want.

Comment: One wild guess you are using `ltxdoc.cls` not directly the doc package and are (now) picking up `ltxdoc.cfg` which is setting a4paper option

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Should I post the three dtx files and the log file?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle AHA! Didn't I read something about that in a recent dev update? That has changed, has it not?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That was it! Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133455/discussion-between-latexerexetal-and-david-carlisle).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two layouts that you show are the result of

```
\documentclass{article}
```

and

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
```

You provided no code but I would guess that you are using `ltxdoc` class and are (now) picking up `ltxdoc.cfg` which does

```
\PassOptionsToClass{a4paper}{article}
```

So you may want to explicitly force letter paper size

Answer (score 0):

(I am not comfortable answering my own question but I want to do it mainly to provide a detailed record of the problem and its solution for beginners. I will not accept my own but rather David Carlisle's because he actually provided the solution.)

David Carlisle mentioned that the `ltxdoc.cls` picks up the configuration file `ltxdoc.cfg` which sets the default paper size to `a4paper`. Sure enough, I looked and the file `/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex-dev/base/ltxdoc.cfg` had a new time stamp of 2021/12/07, and the `doc` package's documentation file shows a date of December 6, 2021.

So something HAD indeed changed! I copied this file directly to my working directory and commented out the line `\PassOptionsToClass{a4paper}{article}` and now everything works as it did on December 5, 2021. CTAN shows that certain parts of the `LaTeX` base distribution were apparently updated on December 6, 2021 and that explains the discrepancy.

In the documentation for the `doc` package there is a solution to avoid picking up `ltxdoc.cfg` and that is to replace `\documentclass{ltxdoc}` in your `.dtx` file with

```
documentclass[options]{article}
\usepackage{doc}
```

I had no idea this distinction even existed and wanted to let beginners know about it.